convert files from multiple csv files to multiple txt files in pentaho
I need to create a job that takes a folder in which only csv files are found but these have the name with the date for example 03-16-2024_shopping in this way x files I would like to take all the files in that folder and transform them to txt keeping the names and that they are all independent, do you know how to do it in advance, thank you very much
If it can be with images it would help me a lot
I have tried multiple solutions but none of them have worked the way I need them to.

How do you think a txt file is different from a csv file ?

It's because the file comes with length, in which it includes zero to complete the length, it doesn't really matter if it continues as CSV, I need to transform the files to weigh less.

it is unknown, to me, what you are trying to transform.  It is also pretty unclear what weigh less does do to a file.

Please give a clear definition of the transformation you want to apply to the data in the csv.. (only maintain certain columns, only concatenate all fields which have value  independent of columns, etc.) Then we can help you out how to solve this.
